# Jenkins Matrix Project: Ignore non existing configurations

Tags: java, jenkins, continuous-integration

We use 3-4 axis's in our matrix projects (OS, ISA, Compiler and more) and are really annoyed by the fact that we have to manually write very complex combination filters only because some configurations don't exist.

Is there a way to tell Jenkins to simply ignore non existing configurations instead of piling them in the queue?